# Code first: does fluent api influence UI?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I'm reading a book written by Julie Lerman on Code First. According to the book, annotations and fluent api give the same result. Everything depends on the style of the developer.

I know that annotations allow both to configure how code first generate database objects and how MVC customize UI elements. Let's say I use [Required, MaxLength(50)]. The attribute will generate a NOT NULL, nvarchar (50) in the database. It also will validate the input for that field.

```
[Required, MaxLength(50)]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

What if I decide to use Fluent API to configure Code first. Am I still going to need annotations to influence UI elements or using fluent API is going to be enough?

**EDIT**

How about annotations, such as Display that serve only for UI purposes? Do they have equivalents? If not, Will I need to use annotaions?

```
[Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Data Annotation is the simplest way of telling a class to enforce some validation rule. You can do the same thing with Fluent API as well. Some people like doing it by data annotations and some people like it by doing with fluent API

**Reasons to like it with Data Annotations**

1) Keep the validation info about my entity in one place along with the entity definition

**Reasons to like it with Fluent API**

1) Keep my entity clean. It will have only my property info. No validation info. Clean and simple POCO. I will write validation on the `OnModelCreating` method in my data context class.

You can not do all Fluent API things with Data Annotations way. the same way you don't have few Data Annotations attributes equivalant not present with Fluent API way ( Ex : HasMinLength) . `HasMinLength` is something we will for our Model validation which usually makes sense in the UI.

For the UI Model Validation, you can not use the Fluent API alone. Fluent API's major role is to look into the fluent configuration we writes and act **when creating the Model(Database)** from the entities. **Remember we are overriding the `OnModelCreating` method to write our fluent API configuration**. So for the UI Validation (of my ViewModel), I would use the DataAnnotation way and use fluent API if i want to define some thing related to my datamodel like Define a foreign key or Map this Entity to a Table with different name etc..

**EDIT :** As per the question edit,

You should make use of the Data Annotations in this case. If you are doing code first. You may remember that that entity is going to be your Database table ( of course you can tell EF to ignore /rename specific columns).  In that case, I would keep my `Entities` clean and Create a `ViewModel` which i will use in my UI. I will add my `DataAnnotations` in my `ViewModel` to handle it. I may write some mapping code which maps data from ViewModel to Model and Model to ViewModel wherever necessary.

Comment: Now it make sense in my head. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

If your entity model classes are doubling as your viewmodel classes, AND you are using the default out of the box DataAnnotationsValidationProvider, then you would need the dataannotations attributes on the model properties to get validation.

However, you should not double your entity classes as viewmodel classes. Take for instance, a controller that needs to have a ReturnUrl property in its model. You wouldn't want this in your entity model / database. Because of differences like this between the View model and the Entity model, the 2 should really be separate (yet cohesive) layers in your application. You can make them cohesive using a library like AutoMapper.

This is one of the reasons I prefer the fluent API. If you stick to the fluent API, then you would never put any attributes on any entity model classes or properties. When it comes time to show, insert, or update data, you put the attributes on the viewmodel classes only.

Also, the [Required] attribute on an entity type performs validation during SaveChanges, whereas a [Required] attribute on a viewmodel performs validation during model binding.

Answer (score 1):

According to Julie Lerman's book on DbContext, you do NOT need any additional annotations to your Fluent API configuration. The Name property will get validated by Validation API as if it had been configured with Data Annotations.

According to the same book, MaxLength and Required are the only validation attributes with fluent API conterparts.