# How to control DisplayNameFor result, when using FluentAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, ef-fluent-api

Working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 app. Using Fluent API to define model maps. I want to change the column name appearance so that if I do a DisplayFor it appears properly. For example, "Action Name", rather than "ActionName".

Currently, my fluent api mapping is....

```
this.Property(t => t.ActionName).HasColumnName("ActionName");
```

I want to put a space between Action and Name so that when the column shows up the table column header will say "Action Name", not "ActionName". So, I thought that this would work....

```
this.Property(t => t.ActionName).HasColumnName("Action Name");
```

But, this results in an error...

```
{"Invalid column name 'Audit Name'."}
```

In my HTML it's setup as...

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ActionName)
```

I was thinking that DisplayNameFor would use the .HasColumnName setting, but apparently not.

I could just type in the HTML directly, but I'm trying to do it "correctly" and understand how this works.

Any suggestions on how to properly do this, so that DisplayNameFor results in "Action Name"?

Thanks!

Comment: Just add a `[Display(Name = "Action Name)]` attribute to your property

Comment: Don't use Entity classes as ViewModels! This is the cause of your problem, you're mixing presentational ("view-level") concerns with persistence-level (database) concerns.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks! But, isn't that data annotation? Is there a way to do it using Fluent API? Or is it acceptable practice to mix both data annotation and Fluent API?

Comment: @Dai .... thanks. That sounds like good advice, with cleaner separation!

Comment: @WebDevGuy2, Not for the `Display` - that's view specific and has nothing to do with your database model. Also refer the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709783/code-first-does-fluent-api-influence-ui) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903509/can-i-replace-some-of-this-with-the-fluent-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could just type in the HTML directly, but I'm trying to do it "correctly" and understand how this works.

Doing things "correctly" means not using Entity classes as ViewModels - they serve different purposes.

A great example of why it's a bad idea to use Entities as ViewModels is a User Account management page, for example, because you will want two `string` password inputs for "New Password" and "Confirm password", but your Entity class will only have a single `byte[]` for the password hash/digest (and a `salt` value too, *I hope*) - so by way of this example I hope you see why you shouldn't use `User` entity as a ViewModel for the `UserEdit` page in your web-application.

I don't know what your application does, and you haven't posted a database design, but just create a different type for your `ViewModel`:

```
class SomePageViewModel {

    [DisplayName("Action name")]
    public String ActionName { get; set; }
}
```

And simply copy the value from your entity object into the viewmodel when you return the view:

```
public ActionResult ControllerAction() {

    // ...

    SomePageViewModel viewModel = new SomePageViewModel();
    viewModel.ActionName = entityObject.ActionName;

    return this.View( viewModel );
}
```

Comment: thanks alot! I'll use the ViewModel with annotations then.